# Understanding liminf of an integral function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let
$$ I(x)=\int_x^\infty \frac{\theta(t)-t}{t^2}dt. $$
I know that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} I(x)=0.$$
This is part of a proof showing that $\theta(x)\sim x$. The author concludes through some work that
$$ \liminf_{x\to\infty}(I(\lambda x)-I(x))>0 $$
for some $\lambda>1$. He then claims that this contradicts the fact above. I am having trouble understanding why this is true. Here is my thought process: can I say that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}I(x)=0 \;\;\implies\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}(I(\lambda x)-I(x))=0\;\;\implies\;\;\liminf_{x\to\infty}(I(\lambda x)-I(x))=0$$
which gives us a contradiction,
or is this not necessarily true?

Comment: Your reasoning is right. The crucial thing is that $\lambda>0$ (that's why $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}I(\lambda x)=0$ and hence your first implication holds).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Have a look at Cauchy's criterion for convergence